# Swift 4 ERROR: Cannot assign to value: 'btn' is a 'let' constant

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am trying to create code that woud return background image of a button on `UICollectionView` inside `UITableView`. Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"InsideCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! InsideCollectionViewCell

    if let btn = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UIButton {
        btn = collectionPics[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't use tags to obtain your views.  Create properties in your cell subclass and then you can access them directly

Comment: Show how `collectionPics` is declared please.

Comment: Friendly advice: you could improve this question by giving it a better title. The error message you are receiving from the compiler is very descriptive, and tells you exactly how to solve the problem (`btn is a let constant` -> yet, you are trying to reassign `btn` to an item from your collectionPics collection.). A better question would be "How can I set the background image on a button in a UICollectionView?". Also, you haven't actually asked a question in your description; you have merely stated facts. It's very hard to answer a question when no question was actually asked :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to set the image within a collection view cell. Assuming that:

- collectionPics : [UIImage]
- btn is set correctly

then you can replace

```
btn = collectionPics[indexPath.row]
```

With (edit: for background image)

```
btn.setBackgroundImage(collectionPics[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I forgot to mention that the image I'm trying to set is of a buttons background image??

Comment: What "does not work"? You asked how to avoid a compilation error and this answer tells you how to avoid that error.